# I want to add a new value in the post meta without deleting the old value

Tags: wordpress, post, addition, meta

I have post meta "metaname" with value "thatsme"
and I want to add a new value "thatsyou" in the post meta "metaname" without deleting the old value "thatsme"

**so the result will be:**

- metaname -> New value
- thatsyou -> Old value

**how to do it in wordpress?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply using `add_post_meta` as normal.

The 4th (optional) parameter is a boolean to indicate whether the meta key should be unique or not:

- `false` means that you can add another entry using the same key
- `true` means WP won't create a new entry or change the old one.

You already have a key set up, presumably using code like this:

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'metaname', 'thatsme');
```

**To add another value,** you just to the same again - I've added `false` for the unique parameter here to highlight it, but it is the default value so there is no need

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, 'metaname', 'thatsyou');
```

**Then to retrieve all the values** of the meta-key, you can do the following:

```
$my_meta_keys = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'metaname', false );   // get all values for this key
if ( ! empty( $my_meta_keys ) ) {
    // loop through all values 
    foreach( $my_meta_keys as $value)
        echo $value;  // or whatever you want to do with it
}
```

**References:**

- [Wordpress Code Reference for add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/)
- [Wordpress Code Reference for get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)